# java interface is analogus to java specification?

Tags: java, interface

Can I take as a example to make me/other understand the diff between a interface and class as

java interface is analogus to java specification(JMS APIs)
Java Class is analogous to implementation(ActiveMQ etc) of the specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to understand the difference is to think that an interface defines *what* an object does, while a class defines *how* it does it.

The analogy that you are suggesting is incomplete, because Java has a concept that is in the middle of an interface and a class, i.e. an abstract class: a specification may be modeled as an abstract class or as an interface.

Comment: thanks for the reply, please give a example of "a specification may be modeled as an abstract class in java"

Comment: @Naroji An abstract class provides a mix of *what* and a *how*, because it has methods that have no implementations the same way they are in interfaces, along with methods that may have implementations, the same way they are in classes. For example, JMS specifies `Message` as an interface, but it could specify it as an abstract class as well: such specification would provide an implementation for common properties, such as `ID` and `priority`, leaving out the "payload" methods to be provided by implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a class and an interface is the  way they are ran. A class has a main method inside of it. Interfaces are like global files you can place methods into. For example, you have the class Blah

```
 public class Blah {

    // NOTICE: this is a method that allows you
    // to perform actions within the method

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // do whatever
    }
 }
```

and you have an interface named BlahInterface

```
 public interface BlahInterface {

     public static void main(String args[]);

     public void sayBlah();

     public int getAmountOfBlahs();

     public String getWhatBlahSays();

     public int setBlahs(int blahNumber);

 }
```

As you can see, the difference between the class and interface is that the class relies on the interface for the methods that it can implement.

You can see that the class allows the main method to run things within itself, but if you were to try to run the main method within the interface, it wouldn't work.

Summary:
The interface is only to initialize the methods that the class can use/run.

Hope this helps!